# is variable number being treated as a string?

Tags: bash, shell-script

This is a script that I got from a book (The Linux Command Line)

```
#!/bin/bash
# trouble: script to demonstrate common errors
number=1
if [ $number = 1 ]; then
echo "Number is equal to 1."
else
echo "Number is not equal to 1."
fi
```

I am confused about the expression:

```
$number = 1
```

Inside the [ command the = operator is used for comparing strings, am I right? or what is happening there?

Strings are identified with and without quotes?

Comment: Bash does not have separate number and string types. Strings for numbers are the only kind of numbers it has. You don't need to put quotation marks around something to make it a string in bash. Quotation marks are only necessary to keep things as being treated as one value rather than multiple values when the string contains spaces or other whitespace.

Comment: @frabjous thank you for the explanation, in the end is sort of a convention to use quotes to 'refer' to strings, but in reality everything is treated as string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between string comparison `[ $number = 1 ]` and numerical comparison `[ $number -eq 1 ]` is that equality means different things based on context.  For example:

```
number="1"
if [ $number -eq 01 ]; then
  echo "true"
else
  echo "false"
fi
```

The above code will echo `true` because `01` is numerically equal to `1`, while, this code block:

```
number="1"
if [ $number = 01 ]; then
  echo "true"
else
  echo "false"
fi
```

will echo `false` because the string `01` is not identical to the string `1`.

Comment: Thank you, I had trouble thinking that using the = operator was doing a numerical comparison

Answer (score 0):

For documentation about the conditional operators, you'll want to refer to

- [Bash Conditional Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions)
- the [`test` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-test)  (aka `[ ... ]`)
- and the [`[[ ... ]]` conditional construct](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b_005b)